# Creating a column displaying query match

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to ask if anyone could offer any advice on Teradata/SQL queries. As part of my day to day responsibilities, I often run string/text/batch searches across a database for large lists of strings/names (e.g., animal species A, B, C, D and these lists could run into 700 or even 1,100 names at a time). I have no issues with pulling and exporting the data via the "LIKE ANY" statement and some '%' characters preceding and following each string.

The issue I come across is SQL/Teradata will give me what I need, but my statement does not highlight which entity was found per a specifc row of data returned from the list I used. In addition, some of the strings can be found across 2-3 different columns, not just 1 column) For example, if I have 700 species of animals and my statement returns 25,000 data points, it would be very beneficial for which string a match was found in a given column and avoid manually creating an additional column and reviewing the data in e.g., excel.

For example, an additional column "Name/entity found for Column 1" where it will display, e.g., match for row 2 was " dog species 124" , row 1,023 was " cat species 456" would prove extremely useful.

Below I am attaching an example statement:

```
      SELECT *
        FROM Table_Animal_Species
        WHERE Date BETWEEN '2005' AND '2010'
        AND
        (
    SpeciesColumn1 LIKE ANY ('%cat 123%', '%dog 456%') Or
    SpeciesColumn2 LIKE ANY ('%cat 123%', '%dog 456%') Or
    SpeciesColumn3 LIKE ANY ('%cat 123%', '%dog 456%') Or
          )
```

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Can one column match several names, i.e. both `'%cat 123%', '%dog 456%'` in `SpeciesColumn1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a column contains only one match you can simply switch to a RegEx instead of LIKE. It's also easier to write, names separated by `|`, but you probably create that list instead of keying it in :-)

```
SELECT 
   regexp_substr(SpeciesColumn1, 'cat 123|dog 456', 1, 1, 'i') AS found_in_column_1
  ,regexp_substr(SpeciesColumn2, 'cat 123|dog 456', 1, 1, 'i') AS found_in_column_2
  ,regexp_substr(SpeciesColumn3, 'cat 123|dog 456', 1, 1, 'i') AS found_in_column_2
  ,t.*
FROM Table_Animal_Species AS t
WHERE found_in_column_1 IS NOT NULL
   OR found_in_column_2 IS NOT NULL
   OR found_in_column_3 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Does Teradata allow the re-user of column aliases in the `where` clause?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yep, it's totally wrong, no Standard SQL, but really nice to have. In many cases it's similar to OUTER APPLY :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you very much for your input. It works like a charm (really helpful)! I would have one follow-up question. Does SQL/Teradata allow one to create a list  separately and then in a simpler way reference it in the regexp_substr function? For example defining/creating Animal list = ["dog123", "cat123", "moose123"]  and then referencing Animal list instead of a long list of names in the regexp_substr? Thank you again for the very thoughtful response!

Comment: `SELECT 'cat 123|dog 456' AS animal_list
   ,regexp_substr(SpeciesColumn1, animal_list, 1, 1, 'i')...` or `with cte as (SELECT 'cat 123|dog 456' AS animal_list)
select regexp_substr(SpeciesColumn1, animal_list, 1, 1, 'i')... from cte`